# Assembling a JMPI instruction in NASM gives the error "parser: instruction expected"

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader

I have this assembly code:

```
fin:   
jmpi 0,0xc200
hlt            ;halt cpu run and wait instructions
jmp fin
```

`jmpi 0,0xc200` is incorrect and I cannot understand what is wrong. I assemble this code with:

```
nasm -f bin bootsect.asm -o bootsect.bin
```

Comment: What CPU architecture are you writing assembly for? This isn't x86; x86 doesn't have a `jmpi` instruction, and its `jmp` instructions don't take a comma-delimited list of arguments. Where are you getting this code from?

Comment: The one interesting thing about your code is the value 0xc200 is that is the BDOS entry point in CP/M. Is this a bootloader for an x86 system? Maybe it is a coincidence so I am asking.

Comment: Thanks for everybody ,this code originates a book named <<30 days,make yourself OS>>and I made some change ,because I aslo learned from linux 0.11 ,but I did not consider architecture.Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you may have been looking at [AS86](https://linux.die.net/man/1/as86) assembly code that use `JMPI` (Inter-segment jump). This is usually referred to as a FAR JMP and is encoded in NASM this way:

```
jmp 0:0xc200
```

In NASM `JMPI` is simply `JMP` and there is a colon (`:`) between the segment and the offset rather than a comma (`,`).

---

If you wish to use AS86 to assemble a bootloader instead of NASM you would have to install the AS86 package and then assemble your code into a binary file this way:

```
as86 -b bootsect.bin bootsect.asm
```

---

It is unclear how you intended to reach the HLT loop after the FAR JMP but you probably meant to do this:

```
fin:
    hlt            ;halt cpu and wait for interrupt
    jmp fin
```